# How to search/know the commiter of source code changed in Git?

Tags: git

I have always wondered to know the commiter/author of a particular piece of code by looking up the git history.

Using git, can I know the author who commited this piece of code by looking in the git history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [git blame](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) to see line by line change.

Comment: Firstly, the OP was asking about Git, not Mercurial, and secondly saying one is better than the other is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Git has multiple ways of showing who changed what.

1. `git blame` shows the changes by author and commit per line as odez909 has answered.
2. Looking at the output of `git log` will also show you who created the change in the author field.
3. `git log` will also show a 'committer' field. This is useful in a distributed version control system like git and it shows the person who added the commit to the repository, and it may not be the author.